# create button for calendar availability

Tags: php

What should I do if I wanna create an availability for the calendar? Means, after the user, click on the date they can know whether the date is available or not. now, my codes are functioning for the user when clicking on it, the form will appear.  hope you guys could assist me.

```html
<body>

    
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
               <img src="img/h3.png" alt="header">
 
                <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
                </div>
            </div>
   
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
   
     <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Car rental form</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
    
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Color</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
        <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; Turquoise</option>
        <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>        
        <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
        <option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
        <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
        <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>
        
      </select>
      

     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start date</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" >
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">End date</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" >
     </div>
      </div>
    
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div>
   </form>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
     <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Event</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
    
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Color</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
        <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; Turquoise</option>
        <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>        
        <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
        <option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
        <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
        <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>
        
      </select>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to check selected dates availability!
As per that, you need four operations:

1. Create a php function that queries those dates wherever you are saving them
2. Get inputs selected dates ( you can use jQuery or JavaScript for that )
3. Make an POST Ajax request, where you call your PHP function
4. Return response to user!

That is your walk through to achieve what you want.

TIPS:
 1.

```
$(document).ready(function({
   $('#start').on('change', function({
      var your_start_date_value = $('#start').val();
   });
});
```

more on that read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/

2. Initialize a ajax request, you can use: Ajax or $.post (which letarally is an ajax request)

   ```
   $.post( "phpfunction/url", { date: "your_start_date_value"} ,function( response) {
     $( ".result" ).html( response); // display results
   });
   ```

For ajax request, read more: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you have any questions, reply to my comment !

Comment: need your help to check this code.. ($(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('startDate').on('change', function({
   var startDate = $('startDate').val();
     });
   });
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },)